# Kali Linux is not showing on booting time

Tags: windows, kali-linux, boot

I have been installed the Kali Linux. Its successfully installed without any error. But after installation while, I tried to reboot the system to start the Kali Linux. There was no option showing for start Kali, Only windows8 option is showing. Please help me guys what is the problem?
I'm already running the windows8 on same system.

Comment: This would probably be more on topic on Superuser SE.

Comment: You probably need to look at your GRUB settings. However, running Kali in addition to another OS can be dangerous. By design, Kali runs as root, which means that it's relatively easy to accidentally perform actions which damage the other OS. I would recommend either having a dedicated Kali system, or running it in a virtual machine within another OS, to ensure that any damage is limited to the Kali instance. This is even more important if investigating any potentially malware infested sites - it's not unheard of for malware authors to target Kali users. It should not be used as a day-to-day OS

Comment: Actually this question is related with Kali-Linux that's why I think this is the place to put my query. @WorseDoughnut

Comment: @AnkitGupta This issue is not in any way related to information security. Just because it occurred on Kali doesn't change that this is simply a Linux issue that should have been asked on the SE designed for that.